# Название отдельного инструмента в программе

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как назвать инструмент внутри компьютерной программы? Например: select в фотошопе, кадрирование, ретушь и так далее. В каждой программе есть подобные отделы. Инструмент? Панель? Закладка?

Answer (score 2):

Отдельный инструмент называется совсем не хитро: **инструмент**. Инструменты могут располагаться на **панелях**, объединённых по группам в соответствии с предпочтениями поставщика ПО или пользователя. Панелей может быть несколько, некоторые из них могут быть одновременно на виду, другие — подключаться разными способами (например: через меню, посредством **закладок**, комбинацией клавиш и т. п.).

Answer (score 0):

> Например: select в фотошопе, кадрирование, ретушь...

Из трёх позиций *Кадрировать* является ***командой***.

*Ретушь* выполняется самим пользователем разными инструментами во встроенных ***подпрограммах*** Фотошопа. В панелях инструментов её не может быть по определению.

*Выбор* — стандартная ***опция***, заложенная в принцип взаимодействия с любой программой.

Comment: Опция - это, кажется, факультативная функция, не числящаяся в числе остальных. Выбор же - в числе освновных. Панель инструментов не может включать инструмент, обозначающий процесс? А если инструмент в значении "функция"?  С помощью какого же тогда инструмента мы производим кадрирование?

Comment: Кадрировать = удалить (ненужное поле). Команда, подаваемая нажатием клавиши Delete. Опция = одна из возможностей любой программы, а Выбор —  общая интерактивная опция, меню.

Comment: Но чтобы кадрировать, необходимо выбрать определенный инструмент слева, представляющий собой такой квадратик с выступающими линиями. Что это за квадратик, чем мы ограничиваем область?